# CUDA: Divergent warps penalty specifics

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to understand what is the penalty for warp divergence in the next piece of code. I understand how warp divergence is handled in principle (predicated instructions for small branches, warp voting and branching for large branches - if all warps agree, otherwise predicated instructions and no branching, same as for small branches). However, I don't understand the specifics - how a while loop with a break/continue is handled.

In the example below, when scrapEverythingCondition() evaluates to true for lane X, which of the following will happen:

1. Evaluation proceeds in the inner loop until n == N_N, lane X evaluates nops the whole time, i is incremented, all lanes now work together.
2. Everyone except lane X does someMoreWork() while lane X evaluates nops, lane X does someCostlyInitialization() followed by n=0 while everyone else evaluates nops, all lanes continue to evaluate the inner loop together (with different n values obviously).
3. Something else I didn't think of.

Code:

```
__global__ void chainKernel() {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while (i < N_I) {
        someCostlyInitialization();
        for(int n = 0; n < N_N; ++n) {
            someStatisticsComputations(n);
            if (scrapEverythingCondition(n)) {
                // Everything we did for current i is no good. Scrap and begin again
                i -= BLOCKS*THREADS;
                break;
            }
            someMoreWork();
        }
        i += BLOCKS*THREADS;
    }
}
```

I tried compiling to PTX and looking at the resulting code but it was too complex for me :(

EDIT: Thanks to Maku for the answer. I was also able to verify the answer using old fashioned printf()s sprinkled around the code. I was able to see which threads got where and in what order, and indeed option 1 is the correct one (lane X is suspended until the inner for loop is exhausted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting doc on this issue: [pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.140.4844&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

From what I understand is that control flow statements (including `break`) define sync points for threads. In your case it would be at
`i += BLOCKS*THREADS;`
So lane X leaves `for` loop and waits for the other threads to reach abovementioned line.

Comment: The link seems to be broken "No document with DOI..."

Comment: As far as I can tell they refer to their MCUDA framework there when they describe sync points. However, they do try to mimic the actual behavior of the CUDA architecture, so your point seems to be valid.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding all threads where scrapEverythingCondition(n) is true are executing what's inside the if block and exit the for loop. All other threads are blocked until this block is executed. When these threads exited the for loop the other trheads will execute someMoreWork();

Try out the NVidia Visual Profiler. It really helps in analysing such issues.

Here are also some information about this (page 13 - 18):
http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/3/34/Darve_cme343_cuda_3.pdf

Comment: I never tried NVidia Visual Profiler, I'll try it now, thanks.

I already saw the document you linked to. Unfortunately, just as everything else I read so far it only discusses the if/else case.

Comment: I tried the profiler, however it did not give me per-thread information, so it did not help in solving the issue.